# Provider network not working if it was created before enabling provider networks

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I have OpenStack deployed using Kolla Ansible. I recently made a change/reconfigure to setup provider networks. I added the external network interface to all of the hypervisors. Every seems configured correctly. I noticed that newly created external networks work perfectly fine when directly attached. Any external network created before the reconfigure does not work at all.

Has anyone else had this issue or have a solution?

I unfortunately can't delete and recreate the network since a lot of instances are using them for floating ips and a couple direct on the neutron controller.

Comment: I should probably mention here in the comments there are no error messages. All of th ip address and network interfaces for the instances all exist and create correctly.

Comment: Have you check the physical  network configure?  I had met this issue because of the switchport didn't allow the vlan.

Comment: I thought the same but the issue remains for another vlan on the same switch. The newly created vlan 560 network in openstack works but vlan 554 and 10 do not since they were previously created in openstack. All three vlans are allowed on the ports.

Comment: My guess is there must be something different that happens when provider networks are created with only an external interface on neutron host rather than when provider networks are created with every host having an external interface.

Comment: The three networks created with the true segment id? What happened while you revert to only with the previous two networks?

Comment: Yes the correct vlan/segment id. I added the third new network in order to test my theory. I tried rebooting a couple hypervisors to see if that would help and it did not. I'm contemplating rebooting the neutron container.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

- You can migrate all those instances to another compute hypervisor
- If after migration they still don't work, you can reboot your compute/network server (one-by-one, if you have multiple) , all those dockers will automatically comeback.

openstack neutron is complicated...does your openstack use ovn or openvswitch?